# My :hover selector is interrupted by text, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-class

So my problem is I have an image that when I hover over it, the box shadow changes color. However, I also have some text on the image that changes when the image is clicked, and the problem is that the area the text is in is preventing my box shadow from taking effect. The shadow only works if I hover over a part of the image that isn't occupied by text. Is there any way to fix this? Also I just realized this will affect when I make a click function as the text may prevent me from clicking the image.

HTML:

```
//The next pickaxe price
<p id="picklvl">Upgrade Pickaxe $<span id="picklvlc">5000</span></p>


//My location for my img
<img id="buy2" src="img/buy2.png">
```

CSS:

```
// Text that displays price of next pickaxe
#picklvl { 
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: fantasy;
    top: 52%;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 130px;
}

// Gives location + shadow to my buy2 image
#buy2 {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 13px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}

// When I hover over buy2, shadow changes color
#buy2:hover { 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #272727;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is laid over your image, so it's normal browser behavior that the hover wouldn't work. Because the text and image are not inside each other but elements on the same level in the DOM, you can only hover one at a time.

A fix to also apply the effect when the text is hovered:

```
#buy2:hover,
#picklvl:hover ~ #buy2 { 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #272727;
}
```